# How to use rails mail_to helper with html_options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
=mail_to "info@somewhere.com", nil, :html_options => {:style => 'font-weight: bold'}
```

renders as

```
<a href="mailto:info@somewhere.com" html_options="stylefont-weight: bold">info@somewhere.com</a>
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just get rid of the `html_options` wrapper:

```
=mail_to "info@somewhere.com", nil, :style => 'font-weight: bold'
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be valid? The docs (http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-mail_to) clearly state that the third parameter is a hash to pass in additional HTML options.

Comment: I agree @Dylan Markow the instructions DO in fact state it is supposed to be html_options: {class: 'something', id: 'something', style: 'something' } but it doesn't work like that.  It DOES work the way that was presented in the answer; despite the rubyonrails.org api docs stating to the contrary.  One of the few complaints I have about Rails, documentation is not that good and sometimes it is just plain false like in this case.